# page not redirecting to self in php

Tags: php

i have a website in php codeigniter, when the user clicks the button, the product is added to cart and the current page itself should be shown. my url looks like below:

```
https://localhost/booktheparty/index.php?/hyderabad/corporate-party-planner/view-corporate-entertainment-activities/ENT105012/50/12
```

and i have used the below code to redirect to self page

```
header("Location: " . "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $location);
```

but its not working, when the button is clicked the page is redirectd to xampp dashboard. what could be the problem?

Comment: If you just want to refresh, then just send that header - `header("Refresh: 0");` instead of `header("Location: .....");` -- your `$location` variable is probably incorrect.

Comment: what is in `$location`?

Comment: where do i set the $location variable and what would i give it

Comment: Use the CI `current_url();` helper `header("Location: ". current_url());`

Comment: @Saad Suri: What is `current_url()`?

Comment: Mentioned in comment it's CI  helper function used to retrieve the current url.

Comment: @SaadSuri actly its a different page

Comment: @ZubairShah You've asked page not redirecting to self. If you want to redirect different page then you should've mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript to reload the page

```
location.reload();
```

Or PHP

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

Instead of passing the URL.

Or PHP with a URI

```
header("Refresh:0; url=" . $location)
```